# Android listview edittext contents not visible

Tags: android

In my android application i created edit texts dynamically and loaded into list view.The problem is i could not to able view the edit text contents while i enter text using key board.The keyboard hide the entered content...

Comment: add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to activity in Manifest file

Comment: it is not working even though i set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" as you said in that activity